# How to animate content offset in collection view in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to move my collection view vertically 5px at a time using content offset using time interval trigger but it's not animating, my code for that is

```
timer = Timer.init(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(animateScroll), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

@objc func animateScroll() {
    self.previousOffset = self.collectionView.contentOffset.y
    self.collectionView.contentOffset.y = self.previousOffset + 5
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly animate UIScrollView contentOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749950/how-to-properly-animate-uiscrollview-contentoffset)

Answer (score 2):

just use method `setContentOffset:animated:`